# Do not show skype call screen

Tags: android, skype

Now, I want to develop a Android app with using Skype voip service.
This app have keypad to input skype ID, and make call to that.
But at that time it will show skype call screen replace my app screen.
I want to make a skype to skype call on my app, but show my app screen and hide skype call screen. Is that possible?

That is SDK i used
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skypeuris/skypesdkforandroid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible using Skype ids. Instead you will have to create your own server or other backend and create an app that manages all the video calling.

Comment: Can I setting priority of display screen on Android? it like show on top property on C#. it's possible?

Comment: It is possible, but would be very buggy and very limited.

Comment: If I helped, be sure to mark my answer as correct by clicking the check mark under my answer.

Comment: Can you show me how to make an application that show on top of skype dealer/caller sceen? Please help and I will marking as answer.

Comment: That is beyond the scope of this website. Look up some tutorials using Google, and if you have problems, post them to this website.